# Transforming Diophantine quadratic equation to Pell's equation

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, quadratic-forms

I have been discussing the fastest and most efficient ways of solving QDEs in a separate question record ([Alternative method to solve quadratic Diophantine equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1720209/alternative-method-to-solve-quadratic-diophantine-equations?noredirect=1#comment3514221_1720209)). However, as suggested by individ, I want to shunt the discussion onto new tracks.
Note also, that I am aware of similar entries related to this topic (like [Solving Pell's equation(or any other diophantine equation) through modular arithmetic.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/422593/solving-pells-equationor-any-other-diophantine-equation-through-modular-arith)) but my questions are slightly different and the special case I am interested in (see below in bullets) does not match the previous QDEs discussed.

Again we have: $$Ax^2 + Bxy + Cy^2 + Dx + Ey + F = 0 $$

where $ A,B,C,D,E,F \in \mathbb Z$

Individ suggested that instead of following a general algorithm proposed by Dario Alpern (https://www.alpertron.com.ar/METHODS.HTM) a more elegant and computationally faster may be a method of transforming QDE into some form of Pell's equation.

The questions are:

- Can any QDE be transformed into some form of Pell's equation? If yes, please provide guidelines.
- If not, then at least is it feasible for $A=1, B=0, C=-1, D=D_0, E=0, F=F_0$ , where $ D_0 > F_0 $ and $ F_0 > 1 $? If yes, then please provide guidelines how to do this at least in outline.
- Does such transformations into Pell's yield any substantial advantage in terms of solving QDE over Alpern's guidelines? **This is perhaps the most crucial question** -- Does solving QDE through Pell's transformation involve finding integer divisors of some linear combination of $D$ and $F$ during the solving process? If so, then the whole idea seems pointless from computational perspective.

Comment: The formula for this equation is very large and bulky.  Might first consider simpler? Such?  $Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2=F$

Answer (score 5):

Legendre has long established this.

> **I. Transformation**

Given ***any*** QDE,

$$ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+f=0\tag1$$

then it can be  transformed to ***two*** *Pell-type equations*,

$$u_i^2-Dv_i^2 = k_i\tag2$$

as,

$$(Dy-2ae+bd)^2-D(2ax+by+d)^2 = 4a(ae^2+cd^2-bde+Df)\tag3$$

$$(Dx-2cd+be)^2-D(2cy+bx+e)^2 = 4c(ae^2+cd^2-bde+Df)\tag4$$

with the same ***discriminant*** $D=b^2-4ac$.

But there is a ***problem***. Once you've found integer $u,v$ then, *by undoing the transformation, it does not guarantee that $x,y$ will be integers* as well.

> **II. Example**

$$4x^2+20xy+5y^2-24x-20y-73=0$$

By formulas $(3),(4)$, this can be transformed to either,

$$p^2-320q^2 = -4\times113920$$
$$r^2-320s^2 = -5\times113920$$

Let's use the [Alpertron](http://www.alpertron.com.ar/QUAD.HTM):

1. It gives a small solution $p,q = 80,38$ which yields rational $x, y = \frac{37}{8}, \frac{5}{4}$.
2. Fortunately, another family starts with $p,q = 640,54$ and gives integer $x,y = 2,3$.
3. We also have $r,s = 280, 45$ which yields $x, y = \frac{11}{8}, \frac{15}{4}$.
4. But $r,s = 480, 50$ gives$x,y = 2,3$.

Thus, if you're not fortunate, you'll only end up with ***rational*** $x,y$.

Comment: Dear Tito ,can you please try to solve this [problem][http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1756575/link-between-the-negative-pell-equation-x2-dy2-1-and-a-certain-continued-fr]

Comment: Is it always true that ONE of the two equations will lead to integral $x,y$, or can it be that both solutions might result in rational [non-integral] $x,y$ only?

Comment: @KierenMacMillan If $(1)$ has integer solutions, then it is guaranteed that at least one of the two Pell-like eqns would lead to that solution. Thus, your question is essentially asking if $(1)$ can only have rational solutions and I'm not sure to the answer to that.

Comment: I only meant the first part of your sentence: if (1) has integer solutions, will undoing the transformation still lead [back] to those integer solutions…

Comment: @KierenMacMillan: Given an arbitrary integer solution $x,y$ to $(1)$, then it corresponds to an integer $u,v$ so undoing the transformation will necessarily lead back to that $x,y$. But not the other way round. Given an _arbitrary_ integer solution $u,v$, then it does not necessarily lead to integer $x,y$.