# A two variable Diophantine equation of degree 3

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I am aware of Legendre's method for solving the Quadratic Diophantine Equation (QDE) of the form

$$
Ax^2 + Bxy + Cy^2 + Dx + Ey + F = 0 \tag{1}
$$

by [transforming them into a Pell-type equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1721471/transforming-diophantine-quadratic-equation-to-pells-equation).

I have the following equation:

$$
x^3+4xy-8(n+1)y+4(n+1)^2=0 \tag{2}
$$

where $n$ is a constant.

The leading monomial is of degree $3$. So it isn't a QDE.

Are there any methods for solving equations of type (2) with a cubic term?

Comment: This particular one is linear on $y$. Solve for $y$, which should be equal to a rational functions of $x$. The denominator is linear too. So, dividing numerator by denominator would give a polynomial plus a proper fraction with a constant on the numerator. There is the minor inconvenience of non-monic denominator, but appropriate multiplication by $4$ and study of cases when that multiplication introduces extra solutions should make it work.

Comment: $y=\frac{x^3+4(n+1)^2}{-4x+8(n+1)}$. We need $x$ even and $n$ odd. So, let's change $x$ with $2z$ and $n$ with $2k+1$. We get $y=\frac{z^3+2(k+1)^2}{-z+2(k+1)}$. Well, now the denominator is monic, easier to do the division.

Comment: @NDB: If you could write this up as an answer, I will accept it and move it off the unanswered queue. Thanks.

Comment: @vvg What is the context of this post? It has a nice expression in terms of powers, $$x^3 + x^2 - (x - 2 y)^2 + 4 (1 + n - y)^2 = 0$$ so doesn't seem to be a random equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The given equation is linear in $y$, so we can readily isolate it to get
$$y=\frac{x^3+4(n+1)^2}{8(n+1)-4x}.$$
For $y$ to be an integer $x$ and $n+1$ must be even, say $x=2z$ and $n=2m-1$, and so
$$y=\frac{z^3+2m^2}{2m-z}=\frac{2m^2(4m+1)}{2m-z}-(4m^2+2mz+z^2).$$
Given that $n$ is a constant, also $2m^2(4m+1)$ is a constant, and now it suffices to check all values of $z$ such that $2m-z$ divides $2m^2(4m+1)$.